# drools 5.5.0 error - Cannot find the declaration of element 'change-set'

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, drools

I am new to Drools, I am using drools 5.5.0 final runtime Maven project in eclipse IDE.

when I run the project in Maven the following error is thrown
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'change-set'.

This is the control flow

1. SampleDroolRule.java

   ```
   public class SampleDroolRule extends RuleTestBase {
     private static List<Object> mockPropertySet;
     public SampleDO runRules(List<Object> mockPropertySet) {
        StatelessKnowledgeSession ks = createRuleEngine("SampleTest.xml", logger);
   ```
2. The 'createRuleEngine' call goes to

   ```
   protected static StatelessKnowledgeSession createRuleEngine(String changeSetXML, Logger logger) {

       logger.info("Creating KS from " + changeSetXML);
       KnowledgeBuilder builder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();

       builder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(changeSetXML), ResourceType.CHANGE_SET);
   ```
3. The builder.add line throws the error

   ```
     [main] ERROR org.drools.xml.ExtensibleXmlParser  - (null: 4, 188): cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'change-set'.
   ```
4. SampleTest.xml looks like this

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <change-set xmlns='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set'
    xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xs:schemaLocation='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set.xsd http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-   api/src/main/resources/change-set-1.0.0.xsd' >
   <add>
   <resource source='classpath:rules/sample/drls/SampleRules.drl' type='DRL' />
   </add>
   </change-set>
   ```

I have spend more that 2 days now. have gone through loads of forums with no luck.
please help me out here.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the spaces (`drools-   api`) from the URL of the xs:schemaLocation might help.

However, I suggest that you modify the `<change-set>` element attributes in your `SampleTest.xml` so that the `xs:schemaLocation` references a local copy of `change-set.xsd` or `change-set-1.0.0.xsd`.

```
<change-set xmlns='http://drools.orchange-set-1.0.0.xsdg/drools-5.0/change-set'
 xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
 xs:schemaLocation='file:///...'>
```

You may find the XML Schema file or files in the sources directory of the distribution archive.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. 
(drools-    api) was a typo from my part. 
Will try to reference my schemaLocation to local copy, and let you know if it works out.

Comment: just gonna try it out now

Comment: refrenced it to local copy, but the same error gets thrown again
    ERROR org.drools.xml.ExtensibleXmlParser  - (null: 4, 135): cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'change-set'.

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace where the XML Parser throws the error? The addition of the change-set XML file should not throw an error, even when the XML Schema is not accessible.

Comment: I get a similar error if I compile and execute using Drools 5.4.0. Are you *sure* you are using 5.5.0? No old jar in the classpath?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I installed Drools tools as eclipse extension from [link](http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/)
Also set DROOLS 5.5.0 runtime

Comment: Then the full stack dump, please.

Comment: The full stack trace is follows:

    'Running com.sample.test.data.matching.MatchingRuleTest
4607 [main] INFO  com.sample.test.data.matching.SampleDroolRuleTest  - Creating KS from MatchingTest.xml
4805 [main] ERROR org.drools.xml.ExtensibleXmlParser  - (null: 4, 135): cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'change-set'.
4812 [main] INFO  com.sample.test.data.matching.SampleDroolRuleTest  - Creating KS from 
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.222 sec <<< FAILURE!'

Comment: Wait a sec. That link http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/org.drools.updatesite/ does not point to a proper full Drools installation.

Comment: Did you get and unpack drools-distribution-5.5.0.Final.zip from http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/?

Comment: This is not the full stack dump - JUnit or similar is hiding the essential parts.

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing the same error. Finally this issue resolved by changing the xml and main class code content as below

and in your main class add below snippet

```html
<change-set xmlns='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set'
             xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
             xs:schemaLocation='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-api/src/main/resources/change-set-1.0.0.xsd' >
  <add>
  <resource source='file:file-path/file-name.drl' type='DRL' />
  <resource source='file:file-path/file-name.bpmn' type='BPMN2' />
   </add>
 </change-set>
```

kbuilder.add( ResourceFactory.newInputStreamResource(new FileInputStream("yourfileName.xml") ),
                  ResourceType.CHANGE_SET );

then place your yourfileName.xml in project root

Hope it helps someone.